# Beaglebone black does not start because the EMMC is formatted

Tags: debian

Recently I formatted the EMMC a Beaglebone Black and after the reboot can not give boot using micro sd. I recorded Debian on micro SD and tried to boot by pressing the "user" button on BB, but nothing happens. Has anyone experienced anything like this? =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Debian on other micro sd and returned to work. Problem was in the micro sd. =D